# Delete with Nhibernate and parameters

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I need to execute a query that delete the records as follow:

```
DELETE FROM News WHERE DateRelease <= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())
```

This is my code

```
public void Removehistory(Int32 daysToKeepFromNow)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Delete("DELETE FROM News WHERE DateRelease <= DATEADD(DAY, -" + daysToKeepFromNow + ", GETDATE())");
    }
}
```

but fire this error:

> Not supported for DML operations [DELETE FROM News WHERE DateRelease
>   <= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())]

I am pretty new to nhibernate, what's wrong with this query?

Comment: SQL syntax looks fine on first pass. I'd add some more tags like C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because session.Delete is not a method to run queries: [Hybernate Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html)

you should instead use `session.createQuery` and then `query.executeUpdate`

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete News where DateRelease <= (sysdate -60)");

int result = query.executeUpdate();

if (result > 0) {
    System.out.println("Old news removed");
}
```